# json.decode and jsonDecode returns object of type _JsonMap

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I started developing a web-only flutter app and am using `dart:convert` library to decode a json. When getting a response from server and decoding it via json.decode, it weirdly becomes a _JsonMap object with _JsonMap objects inside.

Here are my outputs in console while debugging:

```
json.decode('{"data":[{"_id":"64517a0cd447940df60e74c2", "type":["asd", "fds"]}]}')
json.decode('{"data":[{"_id":"64517a0cd447940df60e74c2"}]}')
json.decode('["foo", { "bar": 499 }]')
```

[image: picture]

Creating a new project fixes the issue, but I have no ideas left to debug.

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm64, locale en-UA)
    • Flutter version 3.10.6 on channel stable at /Users/vladli/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision f468f3366c (4 weeks ago), 2023-07-12 15:19:05 -0700
    • Engine revision cdbeda788a
    • Dart version 3.0.6
    • DevTools version 2.23.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/vladli/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.12.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.80.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.70.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 12 mini (mobile) • 1BB27A09-BBE8-44D9-977E-B9D56B962071 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-16-2 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)         • macos                                • darwin-arm64   • macOS 13.0.1 22A400 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 115.0.5790.114

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!
```

The question is – why am I getting this _JsonMap? Looks internal and there is scarcely any information about it online.

Comment: Decoded JSON objects are represented by `Map<String, dynamic>`, but remember that `Map` is an abstract class. `_JsonMap` is a concrete class that extends the abstract class (like other implementations `HashMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, `SplayTreeMap` etc.) You wouldn't be scared that a particular map was actually a hash map, so no need to be scared here it is implemented by some other class.

Comment: What actual *problem* are you encountering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a problem with your code; it's the under-the-hood implementation for `jsonDecode`.

If you were to convert an object to and print it's type, you'll indeed see that it's a `_jsonMap`:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  print(jsonDecode(
          '{"data":[{"_id":"64517a0cd447940df60e74c2", "type":["asd", "fds"]}]}')
      .runtimeType);
}
```

Prints:

```
_JsonMap
```

So you are correct: it seems like calling `jsonDecode` would return a `Map`, however, under the hood, it's really a `_jsonMap`.

---

Don't forget that Dart is open-source. so you can always dig deeper

Comment: yeah, you are correct, thanks. I was buffled by the fact that I got different results in breakpoint-console on mobile app and on web – mobile does not return a _JsonMap